# Query does not work in PHP but works in MySQL directly

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

When I try this Eloquent query I get `0` as the result when I am expecting `217`:

```
OrderItem::whereBetween(
        'created_at',
        [
            DB::raw("CONVERT_TZ('$start_date 09:00:00', '+00:00', '-06:00')"),
            DB::raw("CONVERT_TZ('$end_date 18:00:00', '+00:00', '-06:00')")
        ]
    )->count();
```

If I do `DB::getQueryLog()` on the above, copy the compiled query to execute it raw on the database using MySQL Workbench, then I get the expected results of 217.

```
select count(*) as aggregate 
from `order_items`
where
`created_at` between
CONVERT_TZ('2016-02-17 09:00:00', '+00:00', '-06:00') and
CONVERT_TZ('2016-02-29 18:00:00', '+00:00', '-06:00')
```

Here is the var dump of that query log exactly:

```
array (3) [
    'query' => string (82) "select count(*) as aggregate from `order_items` where `created_at` between ? and ?"
    'bindings' => array (2) [
        Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression (1) (
            protected value -> string (53) "CONVERT_TZ('2016-02-17 09:00:00', '+00:00', '-06:00')"
        )
        Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression (1) (
            protected value -> string (53) "CONVERT_TZ('2016-02-29 18:00:00', '+00:00', '-06:00')"
        )
    ]
    'time' => float 0.41
]
```

What could be preventing the Eloquent implementation from working right?

Comment: One thought... you're using `$date` twice in the Eloquent query and two different dates in the raw SQL, so the two are not identical.

Comment: The `$date` twice was a copy error from my original code. I've updated to reflect that. It was originally supposed to be for the same date different time, but I changed it to allow for separate dates halfway through creating this post.

Comment: The bizarre thing is that this should work even with the same date so long as the time span is different, but no matter which date it has and no matter how many records are between those dates, there are always zero results returned when executed in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

In your query

```
OrderItem::whereBetween(
        'created_at',
        [
            DB::raw("CONVERT_TZ('$date 09:00:00', '+00:00', '-06:00')"),
            DB::raw("CONVERT_TZ('$date 18:00:00', '+00:00', '-06:00')")
        ]
    )->count();
```

I saw that you using $date twice. So the SQL command which is generated by Laravel likes the following:

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `order_items` where between CONVERT_TZ('2016-02-10 09:00:00', '+00:00', '-06:00') and CONVERT_TZ('2016-02-10 18:00:00', '+00:00', '-06:00');
```

You will get the same date in query which different from what you mentioned when copy the sql command.

I didn't see anything not work here

Comment: The `$date` twice was a copy error from my original code. I've updated the original post to reflect that. It was originally supposed to be for the same date, but I changed it to allow for separate dates halfway through creating this post.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
whereRaw("`created_at` between
CONVERT_TZ('2016-02-17 09:00:00', '+00:00', '-06:00') and
CONVERT_TZ('2016-02-29 18:00:00', '+00:00', '-06:00')")
```